# What is autoload in composer.json and how can we use this in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, autoload, composer-php

I am just start working with **Laravel**, want to create a custom class and want to call this class in every controller. For this, I create a `Customer` class in `app/Library/` folder.

When I tried to autoload this library via composer, json it's giving an error:

> Could not scan for classes inside "App/Library/Customer" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder.

How can we use autoload class in controllers?

**Customer.php**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Library;
    use App\Model\User;
    class Customer
    {
        public function login($user_name,$password){
            $data = User::where('email', $user_name)
              ->where('password', $password)
              ->first();
            return $data->id';
        }
    }
```

**Autoload section of Composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Library/Customer"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files" : [
            "app/Helper/helper.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not understanding what the composer autoload is there for. You use this to include libraries and their dependencies, not really for classes you've created in your app.

What you're better off doing is when you create the controller add in the class you want to use eg:

```
<?php
use App\Library\Customer;
```

You will need to put this in every controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove it from the classmap group and just add the proper namespace and class. You can see all the psr-4 standards here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Lets say you have a folder structure like this:

```
app
    -> Library
        -> Customer.php // namespace App\Library; class Customer{}
    -> Model
        -> User.php // namespace App\Model; class User{}
```

And all the files should autoload as long as you use the proper namespace and class names.

By the way you should use the Auth facade instead: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `classmap` as already `psr-4` autoloading is in place. You've to understand how it works. then you can simply import your classes using `use` keyword, like this

```
<?php 

use App\Library\Customer;
```

For more information read [PSR-4: Autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and take this [Tutorial](https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading)